# Is there anyway to set specific order when programatically adding rows to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

Currently I have a DataGridView with a bunch of rows.
I don't have any unique ID column, I'm just grouping rows based on 1 parameter: Camera.

[image: OriginalData]

I was able to create additional DataGridViews for generating groups and log the information (which is oredered as I need):

[image: OrderedLog]

As is logged, all rows are grouped correctly, this log comes from the DataGridViews.

My issue is that when I'm trying to put these ORDERED rows into the original DataGridView, the rows are getting sorted somehow (Idk why):

[image: SortedData]

Even the log from DataGridViews is getting modified:

[image: FinalLog]

I tried to setting:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in logDataGridView.Columns)
{
   column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

to disable sorting on the original DataGridView, even I did it on the additional DataGridViwes, but didn't work.

I'm copying the rows to the original DataGridView with this code:

```cs
DataGridViewRow newRow = (DataGridViewRow)logDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    newRow.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
logDataGridView.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

I have tried many alternatives, even converting the DataSource to DataTable but didn't work neither.

Any suggestion/alternative/codetrick is welcome.

Comment: Sorting or Grouping? Maybe both? Two different things. Perhaps posting the sorting/grouping code might help to determine that. Also, posting the expected input and output **as text** will be a good add.

Comment: I already grouped data into different datagridviews. I just need copy the rows in the order I already have to my original DataGridView. Let's say I have 3 rows into dgv1 and 5 rows into dgv2 (already ordered as I need), when I copy rows from both dgv the rows are sorted somehow, I need to keep the order when transfering data.

Comment: If the 3 grids have the same columns, then just repopulate the result grid. Like: `logDataGridView.Rows.Clear();` then add cloned rows from `dgv1` and `dgv2`. i.e. `logDataGridView.Rows.AddRange(dgv1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow).Concat(dgv2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow)).ToArray());`.

Comment: DataGridViewRow objects should not be directly used to add rows to the DGV.  Instead, a DataTable (or other) should be the DataSource, and rows should be added/removed from the DataTable. The order the rows appear in the DGV will be determined by `dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "<Comma Separated List of Column Names>";`